# scale_x_date() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand how ggplot2 handles breaks and minor_breaks in scale_x_date().

This is a simple time series with monthly data:

```
months <- as.Date(seq(as.Date('2014-09-01'), as.Date('2015-08-01'), by = "1 month"))
values <- sample(1:50, length(months), replace=T)

df <- data.frame(months, values)
```

I'm manually setting the limits for aesthetic reasons:

```
library(lubridate)

my_limits <- c(floor_date(min(df$dates), "year"), ceiling_date(max(df$dates), "year")) # 2014-01-01, 2015-01-01
```

Plot 1 has misaligned minor breaks:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dates, y = values))
p1 <- p1 + geom_line()
p1 <- p1 + scale_x_date(limits = my_limits, breaks = pretty_breaks(), minor_breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))
p1
```

[image]

Plot 2 is identical to plot 1 (having misaligned minor breaks, too):

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dates, y = values))
p2 <- p2 + geom_line()
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_date(limits = my_limits, breaks = date_breaks("1 year"), minor_breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))
p2
```

[image]

Plot 3 has somewhat weird labels (I'd have expected 2014-01-01 and 2015-01-01):

```
p3 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dates, y = values))
p3 <- p3 + geom_line()
p3 <- p3 + scale_x_date(limits = my_limits, breaks = date_breaks("12 months"), minor_breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))
p3
```

[image]

I have two questions: Why is that (what is it good for)? And is there a way to have both the breaks and the minor to match the beginning of a year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like adding expand = c(0, 0) helps.

Plot 4:

```
p4 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dates, y = values))
p4 <- p4 + geom_line()
p4 <- p4 + scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), limits = my_limits, breaks = date_breaks("12 months"), minor_breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))
p4
```

[image]